# Evcache vs redis

Tags: redis, memcached, netflix

I have read that netflix uses evcache , which is a wrapper over memcache and evcache proves better than memcache

In general it is said that redis server as a better cache than memcache, was trying to find the comparisons of redis and evcache.

Does redis scale as well as evcache or memcache? I am assuming that evcache scaling is tried and tested (hence works good for netflix)

Answer (score 2):

EVCache is a functionality add wrapper over memcache. It is an *application* that Netflix devs wrote to add functionality they need in their cache layer while using memcache as the underlying data store. You can write your own EVCache to use redis as the data store

Comparing redis to Evcache is not the correct comparison as they operate on two different layers.

> Does redis scale as well as evcache or memcache?

Redis can scale to many hundreds of thousands of requests per second.

In general, redis is preferred over memcache because of its many in built data structures

Redis is single threaded so once CPU usage hits 80+% it is better to run another instance instead of giving it a bigger server